# Subscribe Subject only after getting data from forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join, subject

I want to pass some data from one module to another module. For that I am using Subject. I have created below subject :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SelectedClusterService {

  constructor() { }

  public selectedClusterName = new Subject<string>();

}
```

I am passing some data from "oneComponent" through above service like this and redirect to "anotherComponent":

```
this.selectedClusterService.selectedClusterName.next(cluster_name);
```

And fetching data to "anotherComponent" like this:

```
this.selectedClusterService.selectedClusterName.subscribe(res => {
  this.selectedCluster = res;
  console.log("this.selectedCluster", this.selectedCluster);
});
```

This is working fine, I am getting data to "anotherComponent". But In "anotherComponent" I am using forkJoin. I want to get data from subject only after getting data from forkJoin.
I am trying like this:

```
   ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin([
      this.dataService.getUpgradeAppList(),
      this.dataService.getClusterList()
    ]).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log("forkJoin :: ngOnInit ::", data);
      this.appList = data[0].apps;
      this.clusterList = data[1];

    }); 
    this.selectedClusterService.selectedClusterName.subscribe(res => {
      this.selectedCluster = res;
      console.log("this.selectedCluster", this.selectedCluster);
    });
  }
```

I have tried `ngAfterViewInit`, `ngAfterContentChecked` with changeDetection also I try to use `setTimeout`, but nothing works. Always I am getting subject data first and then forkJoin data.
How I can get forkJoin first and then subject data?
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Try to use combineLatest instead of forkJoin.

Comment: @EvgenyGurevich same result after using combineLatest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there's no way to guarantee a sequence of getting data in your component as you work with async entities. I would use `BehaviorSubject` instead `Subject` to guarantee that you receive data from other component.

Your service will be like:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SelectedClusterService {

  constructor() { }

  public readonly selectedClusterName = new BehaviorSubject<string | undefined>(undefined);

}
```

Your component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin([
      this.dataService.getUpgradeAppList(),
      this.dataService.getClusterList()
    ]).
    pipe(
      tap((data: any) => {
        console.log("forkJoin :: ngOnInit ::", data);
        this.appList = data[0].apps;
        this.clusterList = data[1];
      }),
      switchMap(() => this.selectedClusterService.selectedClusterName),
      filter(res => res !== undefined)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      this.selectedCluster = res;
      console.log("this.selectedCluster", this.selectedCluster);
    });     
  }
```

In your `anotherComponent` you can use the `switchMap` operator to start receiving data from `oneComponent` and the `filter` to ignore initial value in `BehaviorSubject` that we set to `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It works as expected. I tried one solution that applying setTimeout while sending data from "oneComponent" and it works too. But your solution is much bettter than mine.